# Laravel querybuilder updateOrInsert method leads to error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I got a curl request that calling external API and i got to save the response from it. I already saved the previous results and now i want to create a cronjob that calls the function everyday to update the data from our api source. But when i replace `insert` into `updateOrInsert` method by laravel's querybuilder, It leads me to

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Here is my controller.

```
    public function getProjectList(){
        $this->getToken();
        $request_time = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');
        $sign = md5($this->token.$request_time);

        $url = 'https://cgi.singmap.com/project/queryProject?request_time='.$request_time.
        '&token='.$this->token.'&sign='.$sign.'';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $trimmed = $response['datas'];
        // dd($trimmed);
        foreach ($trimmed as $res){
            $inserts[]=[
                'projectId' => $res['projectId'],
                'projectName' => $res['projectName'],
                'country' => $res['country'],
                'location' => $res['location'],
                'propertyGroup' => $res['propertyGroup'],
                'latitude' => $res['country'],
                'longitude' => $res['country'],
                'unitsNum' => $res['unitsNum'],
                'launchDate' => $res['launchDate'],
                'launchDateAltText' => $res['launchDateAltText'],
                'mainImage' => $res['mainImage'],
                'min_price' => $res['min_price'],
                'max_price' => $res['max_price'],
                'streetAddress' => $res['streetAddress'],
                'tenure' => $res['tenure'],
                'developer' => $res['developer'],
                'streetAddress' => $res['streetAddress'],
            ];
        }
        // \DB::table('xp_ecoprop_projectlist')->insert($inserts);
        \DB::table('xp_ecoprop_projectlist')->updateOrInsert($inserts);
        dd('Data Inserted');
    }
```

Response example

```
array:3 [▼
  "code" => "0"
  "msg" => "SUCCESS"
  "datas" => array:127 [▼
    0 => array:21 [▼
      "propertyGroup" => "D09, D10, D11, D21"
      "country" => "Singapore"
      "launchDateAltText" => "Launched"
      "latitude" => "1.30509901046753"
      "galleryLatitude" => "1.30492997169495"
      "relationId" => "175"
      "launchDate" => "1555689600000"
      "galleryLongitude" => "103.828666687012"
      "unitsNum" => 154
      "mainImage" => "https://img.singmap.com/upload/broke/2029c11d79004b5e915809fbd6e19f7b/0275d26811574de68834663514ee2878/imgs/ffc6d2435f5c43828eb9d2200c6186ff.png"
      "max_price" => 35000000.0
      "min_price" => 0.0
      "streetAddress" => "86, 88 Orchard Boulevard"
      "location" => "D10 - Tanglin / Holland"
      "completionDate" => "1640966400000"
      "developer" => "Granmil Holdings Pte Ltd"
      "projectName" => "Boulevard 88 (D10)"
      "projectId" => "0275d26811574de68834663514ee2878"
      "tenure" => "Freehold"
      "projectTitle" => "Boulevard 88 (D10)"
      "longitude" => "103.827575683594"
    ]
```

Comment: `updateOrInsert` only for one record.

Comment: okay i see @TsaiKoga. do you know any method suitable for my case?

Comment: you use mysql  `on duplicate key update` feature

Comment: is that for raw sql only @TsaiKoga? Does querybuilder does have that? can you give me example please?

Comment: which columns are the duplicated-key for updating?

Comment: what do you mean by that? i think its `projectId`. @TsaiKoga

Comment: I mean if there is a column's value has already exists in db. then it will update that row. Or it just inserted it.  What is this column name? If it is `projectId`, you need to unique on this column

Comment: i got a column `id` there but i can make `projectId` as a unique. Can you help me with this @TsaiKoga